# How to handle access to Views if the user is not authenticated yet?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

My Vaadin 14's mainpage is a MainView with the root Route.

`MainView` is used as a "template" for the other View (with `layout = MainView.class`) so I see it more like a "abstract" view that should not be initialized by itself and is only used for the other views as layout.

Now the issue: If a user accesses the `MainView` the **`BeforeEnterEvent` is called AFTER the constructor**. This may lead to exceptions thrown because the user is not authenticated yet and the constructor executes stuff like building the Tabs already.

**Is there a way to prevent the user from accessing the route of the MainView or an event that is executed before the constructor is called?** Accessing the View is only allowed if the user is authenticated.

```
@Route("")
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

public MainView() {
    super();

    // Creates all the Tabs that are used in the MainView, may throw exception if the user calls the URL of this View before authenticated
    setupView();
}

...

@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    // Reroute to Login if User is NOT authenticated
}
}

@Route(value = "foo", layout = MainView.class)
public class OtherView {
```

**Update:**

The fix is released as experimental feature in [Vaadin 14.2](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/14.2.0.alpha4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The issue with instances being created too early](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4595) was actually closed a few hours ago. It will take some time before it's released.

That being said, an instance method can't possibly be called before the constructor, so it does not fix your particular case.

I would suggest moving your view setup code to `onAttach`. If you only want to run the setup code once, you can use `AttachEvent#isInitialAttach` to only execute your code on the first attach.

Once the issue I linked above is released, you can have the code in the constructor, but the instance that has the observer method will still be created before `beforeEnter` is called, just not the child view instances.

To not have any views created, you can add listener directly to the UI using `UI#addBeforeEnterListener` as soon as the UI is created, utilizing a [UI init listener](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-ui-init-listener.html). Again, only when the fix has been released.

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue. I was not aware that it is a known issue. I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code **may have a security issue**, as described in the [tutorial series for spring security with Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security). it is explained [how to secure Views](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security#_secure_router_navigation) in the `VaadinServiceInitListener` instead.

But the proposed solution also adds a beforeEnterListener to the Views, so I don't think your problem is resolved with this.
A solution to your problem may be to throw a custom Exception (let's call it NotAuthorizedException for further reference) in the constructor of MainView if the user is not authorized. Then you let your LoginView implement [`HasErrorParameter<NotAuthorizedException>`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-exception-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it temporarely with an additional check for authentication. It may not be the best solution but it works for now. In the future @Tazavoo's answer should be implemented.

```
public MainView() {
    super();
    if (!isAuthenticated()) 
       return;

    setupView();
}
```